# How to group by incuding UID column in the new table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I 'm trying to group some data with the following query but I need also to **add the uid column from a_import.veg** table in the c_schema.worst_case table which contains unique values. As far as I know I can't add it as usual cause group by doesn't work properly as it takes all the unique ids in the new table... Is there any way to do this?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS c_schema.worst_case
as SELECT back_str, ahead_str, substr(weather_case, 1, 4), min(min_dist) as min_dist
FROM a_import.veg
GROUP BY back_str, ahead_str, substr(weather_case, 1, 4)
ORDER BY back_str, ahead_str;
```

Comment: What about using `min(uid)`?

Comment: This doesn't return the correct ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (back_str, ahead_str, substr(weather_case, 1, 4)) v.*
FROM a_import.veg v
ORDER BY back_str, ahead_str, substr(weather_case, 1, 4), min_dist;
```

(Select the columns you actually want.)

Actually, Postgres now supports `LEFT()`, so you can shorten this to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (back_str, ahead_str, LEFT(weather_case, 4)) v.*
FROM a_import.veg v
ORDER BY back_str, ahead_str, LEFT(weather_case, 4), min_dist;
```